# How can I parse nested arrays?

Tags: c++, json, parsing, boost, nested

I have a JSON that looks like:

```
  "results": [
    {
      "plate": "FRJ7248",
      "confidence": 94.583724975586,
      "matches_template": 1,
      "plate_index": 0,
      "region": "us-ny",
      "region_confidence": 88,
      "processing_time_ms": 94.328330993652,
      "requested_topn": 25,
      "coordinates": [
        {
          "x": 1545,
          "y": 233
        },
        {
          "x": 1640,
          "y": 241
        },
...
...
```

and I'm wondering how I parse the `coordinates` array, I've tried the following:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& v, pt.get_child("results")) {
    ptree subtree1 = v.second.get<string>;
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& w, subtree1) {
        LOG_NS_INFO << "OpenALPR     X  " << w.second.get<string>("x");
        LOG_NS_INFO << "OpenALPR     Y  " << w.second.get<string>("y");
    }
}
```

but got

```
error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::property_tree::ptree {aka boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ requested
             ptree subtree1 = v.second.get<string>;
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with boost, but shouldn't it be `v.second.get<string>()`?

Comment: As the error message hints at, you forgot to call `get`. My first guess would be that you should write `v.second.get_child("coordinates")`.

Comment: @molbdnilo you can move this into an answer and i'll accept it! I needed `ptree subtree1 = v.second.get_child("coordinates");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says `"conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’"` because you didn't *call* `get`.

But you shouldn't use `get`, you should do the same thing as you did for `"results"`:

```
ptree subtree1 = v.second.get_child("coordinates");
```